# While clicking textbox,border for textbox should be transparent

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I was designing a login page,

when i was compiling this in IE,when i click the text box for input ,it shows the whole text box,But i tried this code for hiding the text box

`border: none;  border-color: transparent;`

Comment: when i press the texbox,the texbox should gets disabled,but text should be entered.

Comment: textbox should be disabled but user can enter text? Doesn't make sense to me

Comment: Also specify the version of IE

Comment: @Mr.Alien:It should work as textbox,but when i click the text box,the border should disable.Now can you try something,also i checked it in IE 8

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for your textbox

```
border:0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean outline border? Just use this css:

```
outline: 0;
```

Try this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nG85b/)

Answer (score 0):

how about

```css
.customText:focus {
    border-color: transparent;
    outline:0;
}
```

is this what you are looking for?
http://jsfiddle.net/7azotxfj/1/